# Textbox Only Accepts Dot( . ) And Dash( - )

Tags: c#, textbox, numbers

I Tried Some Codes But Didnt Work

For Example
I Found This And It Didnt Work:

```
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) 
        && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) 
        && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    // only allow one decimal point
    if (e.KeyChar == '.' 
        && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Which event handler is this?

Comment: What is the valid output? OK, one `.` what about the `-`? Other characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a very simple, yet understandable error there.

The `Handled` property of `KeyPressEventArgs` should be set to true to keep the operating system from further processing the key.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs?view=netframework-4.8

In other words, set this to true when you want to PREVENT the key.

Therefore, change your code like this to ALLOW further processing when the pressed key fits the conditions.

Please also see how the boolean variables are introduced to make the code readable.

The code below allows

- A ( - ) character if it is the first char in the text box
- A ( . ) character if it is not the first char and if there are no other dots
- Any control characters
- And any digits.

Good luck.

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        bool isControl = char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
        bool isDigit = char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar);
        bool isDot = e.KeyChar == '.';
        bool alreadyHasADot = (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') != -1;
        bool isHyphen = e.KeyChar == '-';
        bool isFirstChar = (sender as TextBox).Text.Length == 0;

        bool isAllowed =
            isControl ||
            isDigit ||
            (isDot && !isFirstChar && !alreadyHasADot) ||
            (isHyphen && isFirstChar);

        if (!isAllowed)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Im Getting This Error:



```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Nesne başvurusu bir nesnenin örneğine ayarlanmadı.'

(... as System.Windows.Forms.TextBox), null döndürdü.
```

Comment: Hi. Works for me. Can you please post the latest version of your code? The `sender` is always a text box if this is a `TextBox` event handler

Comment: @SelimEmin In which event handler you are executing this code?

Comment: oguz ozgul i dont know

Comment: What I mean is, you need to set the KeyPress event handler of the text box (during design mode, in the properties window) so that whenever a key is pressed into the text box, this method is invoked by the runtime.

Comment: Good to hear that. :)